# Editing Hosted Webpages in IIS

Tags: css, visual-studio, file-upload, iis-7.5

I am very new to IIS in general, but I have recently published a webpage for a client on a IIS 7.5 server.

What is the best, or a good practice to editing webpages?

I am trying to make some CSS adjustments for mobile devices accessing the webpages, and it is easiest if I can do live testing where I just access the site using an ipad/iphone/andorid device. But it is a pain to copy the files over to the server, upload the new files, then test.

Is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Running windows server 2008 btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to make a dummy site to test new functionality before replacing production.

My QC cycle consists of:

**Local Development and Testing**
I have a local setup built through WAMP.  This allows me to develop and see my changes while I am coding.  The issue with mobile development is that it's hard to get a local server to show up on a mobile device.  So I make a Dummy site

**Dummy Site**
I created a Dummy site that is used to test everything I can't test on my local such as mobile views.  I make them a subwebsite of the one I am editing.  Example mysite.com would be testing.mysite.com

**After Testing**
I copy my new site over after testing.